# SQL Relationship to Secondary Table Without Adding Duplicate Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, relationship

There are Cities, Job Types, and Tasks.  Cities can have multiple Job Types.  Tasks are created for a City that can have multiple Job Types.  Cities can have Many Tasks.  But when adding the Job Types for the Tasks assigned to a City, must make sure the City has that Job Type.

How to create Relationship/Constraint when Adding/Updating Task_JobTypes to make sure the City associated with the Task has that Job Type allowed in City_JobTypes? The constraint in Task_JobTypes "FK_Task_JobTypes_JobTypes" need to be referencing that instead of just JobTypes.

Cities - Id,Name

JobTypes - Id,Name

CityJobTypes - CityId,JobTypeId (Allowed Job Types per City)

Tasks - Id,CityId,Name (Task for City)

TaskJobTypes - TaskId,JobTypeId (JobTypes per Task)

Tables -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cities](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Name] [varchar](500) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Cities] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO    

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JobTypes](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_JobTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO    

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City_JobTypes](
    [JobTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CityId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[City_JobTypes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_City_JobTypes_Cities] FOREIGN KEY([CityId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Cities] ([Id])
GO    

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[City_JobTypes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_City_JobTypes_JobTypes] FOREIGN KEY([JobTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[JobTypes] ([Id])
GO 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CityId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tasks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tasks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Tasks_Cities] FOREIGN KEY([CityId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Cities] ([Id])
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task_JobTypes](
    [TaskId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JobTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [IX_Task_JobTypes-TaskId,JobTypeId] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [TaskId] ASC,
    [JobTypeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task_JobTypes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Task_JobTypes_JobTypes] FOREIGN KEY([JobTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[JobTypes] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task_JobTypes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Task_JobTypes_Tasks] FOREIGN KEY([TaskId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Tasks] ([Id])
GO
```

Comment: Why "without adding duplicate column"?  Without that information, it can't be done.  You should add `JobType` to the list of Tasks that are associated to a city.  Then you can constrain that against all the tables you need to, using composite keys.

Comment: Just that adding another column (CityId) to TaskJobTypes that references the city that the task already references, seems redundant. Everything else already has relationship, is that the only way? This is just one example of many tables in database that have setups like this, and to add additional column only seems redundant but if it’s only option (or easiest/cleanest), that’s what I was trying to see

Comment: Sometimes, if I'm adding another column to a table to enforce such a constraint (like `CityId` here), I'll name the table `_TaskJobTypes` instead, the column `_CityId`, and then create a view called `TaskJobTypes` that hides the column (plus triggers to populate that column during `INSERT`/`UPDATE`). *You* know that your db has the extra column, the *users* of your database don't need to (since they still just `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` against that view instead of the table)

Answer (score 0):

> How to create Relationship/Constraint when Adding/Updating
>   Task_JobTypes to make sure the City associated with the Task has that
>   Job Type allowed in City_JobTypes?

You can do this with a [CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) that calls a function.   The function would take the `TaskID` and `JobTypeID` as parameters and query the `Tasks` table joined to the `City_JobTypes` table to see if that `City` has that `JobType`.  Then the function would return True `(1)` if the city has the job type, or false `(0)` if it doesn't.

Alternately, you can also do this with a TRIGGER, but I prefer CHECK CONSTRAINTS personally.

Comment: The problem with doing it via a check constraint like this is it doesn't prevent someone *deleting* a row from `City_JobTypes` that is "referenced" by a row in `Task_JobTypes`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever True, if rows can be deleted from that table, then the Referential Integrity would have to be handled by a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you're philosophically objecting to `composite keys`.  The link table `City_JobTypes` has a composite primary key of `CityId, JobTypeId`.  Any other table that constrains against `City_JobTypes` needs to constrain against its primary key.  That happens to be two columns, but it's still a single key.  I don't see the problem there.

The way I see your structure is...

***A `Task` belongs to a single `City` and has a single `JobType`.***

As a Job must have **one** `City` and **one** `JobType`, make those attributes of the `Task`?

```
City
 ↑
Task → JobType
```

***A `City` also has 0..many `JobTypes` that it is "allowed".***

```
City ← City_JobTypes
 ↑          ↓
Task → JobType
```

***At this point your `Task` table Already has a `CityID` and a `JobTypeID`.***

Why not constrain that composite key against the `City_JobTypes` table?

```
City ← City_JobTypes
 ↑   ↗      ↓
Task → JobType
```

***If a single `Task` can actually have 0..many `JobTypes`...***

I'd start here, which doesn't have any way that I Can see to restrict the `Tasks` based on the `City_JobType` links...

```
City ← City_JobTypes↘
 ↑                   JobType
Task ← Task_JobTypes↗
```

Then I'd decide that the `Task` can reasonably be identified as a `CityTask` with a composite primary key.  This would allow the following.

```
   City  ←    City_JobTypes ↘
   ↑          ↑     ↑        JobType
CityTask ← CityTask_JobTypes↗
```